# How can i detect if a character is already inside another gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

    enum MoveProperties
    {
        DirectionStart,
        DirectionEnd
    };

    public float spinSpeed = 2.0f;

    private bool rotate = false;
    private bool exited = false;
    private List<GameObject> prefabs;

    private void Start()
    {
        InstantiateObjects gos = GetComponent<InstantiateObjects>();

        prefabs = new List<GameObject>();
        prefabs = gos.PrefabsList();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Player entered the hole");
            rotate = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Player exited the hole");
            rotate = false;
            exited = true;
        }
    }

    void Rotate()
    {
        if (rotate)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, spinSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            spinSpeed += 1f;
        }
        if (rotate == false && exited == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, spinSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            if (spinSpeed > 0.0f)
                spinSpeed -= 1f;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
            Rotate();
    }
}
```

There are two triggers here:

OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit.

But this triggers will work if the character first went out and then went in again. Or went out. But i need to detect while the character is already inside.
Without first going out and getting in again.

The situation is that the character is first in one place(hole inside a object) and then i change the character position to another object with hole. After changing the position i need to detect somehow that the character is inside the second hole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But this triggers will work if the character first went out and then
>   went in again. Or went out. But i need to detect while the character
>   is already inside. Without first going out and getting in again.

You are looking for the [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) function. As long as both Colliders are inside one another, `OnTriggerStay` will always be called every frame.

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{

}
```

There is also [`OnCollisionStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html) if you decide to use Collision instead of a trigger.

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo) 
{

}
```